# Email alerts for customer community users

Tags: customer-community, email-alert

I have following problem:

I created a workflow rule(Workflow's object is **User**) which fires when user with license *Customer Community Plus Login* is being deactivated. This workflow rule sends an email alert.

Email alert's object field is set to **User**

Email alert's recipient field is set to **Email Field: Email**

Email is send, but {!Receiving_User.X} (Where X is any User field) isn't populated in sent message.

Anybody got the same problem? Anybody found a solution?

Comment: Receiving-user might pull fields from contact object.. Check that

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Result is the same. All following fields aren't rendered in an email: {!Receiving_User.Contact.Firstname} {!Receiving_User.Contact.LastName} {!Receiving_User.Contact.Name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after digging some information in google I stumbled upon this page: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=merge_fields_email_templates.htm

Use of **Targer_User** merge field solved my problem.

Comment: For anyone coming along later, this info has moved slightly.  As of now you can find it here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_email_templates_cex.htm&type=5